# Cannot use <phone:PhoneApplicationPage />

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, dll

I'm developing an `windows phone app for 8.1`
I'm trying to make a side menu like Facebook does in their apps. 
I found this tutorial:http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.be/2013/08/add-lateral-menus-to-windows-phone.html

Now when I download the source code i see that the `xaml` uses the `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage />`

I have this piece of code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="Membr2.BlankPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="using:Membr2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

But it keeps giving me these two errors:

```
 - Unknown type 'PhoneApplicationPage' in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone' 
 - The type 'phone:PhoneApplicationPage' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
 - The name "PhoneApplicationPage" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone".
```

I've added the following references:

- Microsoft.Phone
- Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit

The `PhoneApplicationPage` is found in `Microsoft.Phone`

So I don't have any idea of what I'm doing wrong? I'm very knew to windows Phone development and those references is driving me nuts... Anybody can help give me a better understanding?

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

You are making a windows phone 8.1 application and `<PhoneApplicationPage>` is part of windows phone 8 Silver light.

You should use `<Page>` instead of `<PhoneApplicationPage>` because former is used for `WinRT`.

Comment: So I'm not able to use this tutorial?

Comment: you can but you will have to modify it with respect to windows 8.1 Api's like replace <PhoneApplicationPage> with <Page> and so on if required